# Moving a box to the top (z-index)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, z-index, jquery-events

I have an application that works like a virtual desktop, with a toolbar with icons that's clickable. When an icon is clicked a window like box is opened (created dynamically) with different content regarding which icon was clicked.

With a function called `moveOnTop()` (see below) that gets called when a window gets created a click event is bound to that window. If several windows is opened and the user clicks on a window that's ordered behind another window the clicked window is moved to the top.

Now to the problem...

When clicking one of the icons, a box is opened showing a bunch of thumbnail images, and when clicking on one of the thumbnails a new window is opened with that particular image. That window with the image should be moved to the top, but that doesn't happen due to that the click event on the thumbnail box that was clicked gets fired after the window with the image gets created, which leads to that window being moved to the top.

I didn't know how to explain the problem in other words and I hope you can understand what I mean.

```
Windows.prototype.buildWindow = function(){

    // a function that created the boxes

    Windows.prototype.moveOnTop();
}

Windows.openedImg = function(){

    // a function that creates the box with the clicked image

    var thisWindow = $(this);
Windows.prototype.getZindex(thisWindow);
}

Windows.prototype.moveOnTop = function(){

var boxes = $('.window');

    boxes.click(function() {
    
        var thisWindow = $(this);
        Windows.prototype.getZindex(thisWindow);
    });
}

Windows.prototype.getZindex = function(thisWindow){

var boxes = $('.window');
var maxZindex = 0;

    boxes.each(function() {

        var zIndex = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);
        maxZindex = Math.max(maxZindex, zIndex);
    });

thisWindow.css("z-index", maxZindex + 1);
}
```

Comment: Instead of shuffling Z-indices why not add a few class names that override the z-index. That way if you remove the class names, it reverts back to its original z-index.

Comment: Gotta say im not digging the way you created this window object: `Windows.prototype.buildWindow`, `Windows.openedImg`. And you calling things using `Windows.prototype.func();` I don't like it at all sir, not one bit.

Comment: Thank you @Chad for the constructive criticism, it was very rewarding! *sigh*

Comment: Honestly you should do a couple things: you should build this object using a cleaner method, you should be using some class to identify active windows not just incrementing z-index each time, and I don't see code that you use to call creating your image window, nor do I understand why you chose to say `Windows.openedImg` instead of `Windows.prototype.openedImg` like you did with everything else. Nearly all the code I see should be rewritten IMO.

Comment: Yes, I know you're right about that cleaner method which is something I'll try to do later on. Regarding Windows.openedImg (that should actually be "Windows.bgChanger.openedImg". This is a function that's not directly related to Windows, but to the specific application "bgChanger" that inherits from the object "Windows". However I totally understand that this is impossible to know from the code. I appreciate your thoughts on my code however!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:

```
<img onclick="openWindow(true)" ... />
```

Javascript:

```
function openWindow(doNotGoToTop) {
    ... //open window
    if (!doNotGoToTop) {
        ... //go to top
    }
}
```